# How to connect 4K monitor to MacBook with 1st gen Thunderbolt?

Tags: nvidia, macbook

I'm using a 2012 non-Retina MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt 1. It can handle 4K but only at 30Hz, and I'm running it this way in Mac OS using SwitcResX. I also did this in Win 7 a couple of years ago by creating custom profile in the NVidia Control panel. My question is - how can this be done in Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu 20 LTS with proprietary drivers 340.